# Can I join two Select sum SQL queries from the same table but with different filters?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sum

I am running into a problem where I am trying to add two SELECT sums from the same table but with different conditions into one single result.

Here is the code:

```
DROP TABLE Match CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE Match 
(
    Heim VARCHAR(50),
    Gast VARCHAR(50),
    HeimP NUMBER,
    GastP NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO Match 
VALUES ('Bayern München', 'Borussia Dortmund', 1, 1);

INSERT INTO Match 
VALUES ('Borussia Dortmund', 'Bayern München', 0, 3);
INSERT INTO Match 
VALUES ('Bayern München', 'Schalke', 3, 0);
INSERT INTO Match 
VALUES ('Schalke', 'Bayern München', 0, 3);

COMMIT;


SELECT SUM(HeimP) AS Heimpoints 
FROM Match 
WHERE Heim = 'Bayern München';

SELECT SUM(GastP) AS Gastpoints 
FROM Match 
WHERE Gast = 'Bayern München';
```

Comment: Your RDBMS  and version? And we can assume that 'Bayern München' is never `Heim` *and* `Gast` at the same time? (Is there a `CHECK` constraint to make sure?)

Comment: This is a test database and it is only used for educational purposes. But yes I should have built in constraints. Thanks for the hint and for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression inside `SUM()`:

```
SELECT SUM(
         CASE 'Bayern München'
           WHEN Heim THEN HeimP 
           WHEN Gast THEN GastP
         END
       ) AS points 
FROM Match 
WHERE 'Bayern München' IN (Gast, Heim);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=99857d79c91afa1239f3b5f54495333b).
Results:

```
> | POINTS |
> | -----: |
> |     10 |
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to replace the conditions in the `where` clause with conditions in a `case` expression and only sum the relevant rows:

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE heim WHEN 'Bayern München' THEN heimp END) AS Heimpoints,
       SUM(CASE gast WHEN 'Bayern München' THEN gastp END) AS Gastpoints
FROM   match
WHERE  'Bayern München' IN (heim, gast) -- optimization to not query useless rows
```

Answer (score 1):

The `NUMBER` makes me think you are using Oracle.  That is a database that supports lateral joins (which are standard SQL but not supported by all databases).

Something like this might be the simplest solution:

```
select sum(x.points)
from match m cross join lateral
     (select m.heimp as team, m.heimp as points from dual union all
      select m.gast, m.gastp from dual
     ) x
where x.team = 'Bayern München';
```

This has the advantage over other solutions of only referring to the specific team once (so avoiding typos).  Perhaps more importantly, it easily generalizes
to all teams:

```
select x.team sum(x.points)
from match m cross join lateral
     (select m.heimp as team, m.heimp as points from dual union all
      select m.gast, m.gastp from dual
     ) x
group by x.team;
```

In databases that don't support lateral joins, you can do something quite similar using `union all`.

Comment: How can any join be simpler than a simple table scan?

Comment: That is correct , I am using SQL Developer. Sorry I forgot to up that in the initial Question. And yes that also works for me. I am trying to understand SQL so thank you for your Advice.

Comment: @ChristopherWilger . . . SQL Developer really has nothing to do with this.  Oracle supports lateral joins.  Forpas doesn't understand them, so just ignore that comment.